# Instagram clone app bypasses login page even if user is not logged in

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am creating an instagram clone app. I have a login view controller which redirects the user to the table view controller after the user logs in. 
Also, the user doesn't have to log in if he's already logged in. I am using the following code to achieve that.

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("userlist", sender: self)
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine. However this happens even when a user is NOT logged in! How do i fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you're using ["Anonymous Users"](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-anonymous-users) feature?
BTW, you should reflect in your question that you use Parse SDK.

Comment: Hi, i am not using the "Anonymous users" feature. And yes, i am using parse SDK.

Comment: And surely you do `PFUser.logOut()` somewhere in the app?

Comment: Hi, I am not using PFUser.logOut(). However, if i delete the app and then install it again, shouldn't it show me the login screen?  I ran it on my simulator as well for the first time. It didn't show me the login screen (I usually run it on my iphone) 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your App Delegate, just before the "return true" in didFInishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
  let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    if currentUser != nil {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        let controller1 = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourControllerstoryboardID") as! yourController
        self.window?.rootViewController = controller1
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Note that in order for this to work, you have to give the view controller--the one you want to jump to if there IS  a user, a storyboard ID. You do this in the inspector panel.

this will make it so that if there is a current user, it will jump past the login screen. Otherwise, it will show the log in screen.

Comment: and delete the code from the viewWillAppear that you posted. I used the above^ in my app that is in the app store and it works fine.

Comment: hey joey. Thanks for your reply. However i found the solution to this and its very simple. All i have to do is replace PFUser.currentUser() != nil with PFUser.currentUser().objectId != nil

This works!